# CIDR Block Overlapping in AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, subnet, amazon-vpc

Can someone please explain Subnet Overlapping with an example ? I'm preparing for AWS CSA and I came across this term. I tried few resources but it's not 100 % clear to me.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS does not use the term "Subnet Overlapping", but there's a few rules around overlapping subnets:

- Within a VPC, the CIDR range assigned to subnets cannot overlap
- When using VPC Peering to connect two VPCs, the VPC range cannot overlap

For advice on preparing for the **AWS Certified Solutions Architect - Associate** exam, see: https://aws.amazon.com/certification/certification-prep/

(I always recommend reading the Amazon EC2 and Amazon S3 manuals, as well as reading the FAQs and whitepapers referred to by that page.)

Comment: Many thanks John ! I guess I wanted to know more about subnet overlapping in general.

Comment: @John Rotenstein I arrived at your answer from the AWS docs (which use the term overlapping) a few times.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Subnets.html